# How to keep unsaved file into vs code workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I close the workspace without saving my file and then reopen the workspace, my file disappears. In Sublime Text this works great for projects (analog workspace for me). How to avoid this problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 79):

In VS Code 1.19 you can use the `files.hotExit` setting:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, "files.hotExit": "onExitAndWindowClose" is a solution to this problem.

Comment: Alternatively, if you came here wondering why VSCode keeps your "scratch pad" text files around even after you closed it, you will probably want this setting set to "off".